# Why does my FB.api request always produce an error response?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

I have a Facebook app with namespace 'thenovel'.  It has an action 'rate' assigned to an object 'sentence'.  When the 'dofacebookstuff()' function is called, I want the user's rating of a sentence - 'testsentence', for the moment - to be published to their timeline.  'Rating' doesn't require an access token.

Whenever the dofacebookstuff() is called, the error alert pops up.  I have tested whether the '!response' or 'response.error' was causing it, and it is the 'response.error' every time.

I can get the user id, name etc. fine with FB.login but the api call just does not work.  If I go straight to 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/thenovel:rate?sentence=testsentence&access_token=XXXXX', I see the following:

```
{
"data": [   ],
"paging": {
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/thenovel:rate?sentence=testsentence&access_token=XXXXX&offset=25&limit=25"
}
}
```

I have checked my HTML and all the Facebook-related stuff is there and in the right place.  None of the other scripts on the page produce errors.  Here is the function in question:

```
function dofacebookstuff() {
    FB.api(
          '/me/thenovel:rate?sentence=hello&access_token=' + accesstoken,
          'post',
          function(response) {
             if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
             } else {
                alert('Action ID: ' + response.id);
             }
          });
    }
```

Could anyone explain where I'm going wrong?  Where is my response data?

Answer (score 1):

If you're posting to `/me` you need an active access token for that user - do you have one? it may have expired already, but i think the message is specifically referring to the fact that you haven't provided one, as there'd be a specific message if the token is invalid or expired.
You should be able to post to `/USER_ID/thenovel:rate` with the [app access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/) if you're doing offline publishing of some kind

Comment: Thanks. I now have an active access token, so my code is as above.  It still says "Error occured".

Comment: Nothing more specific than that? :/

Comment: '{ "data": [   ], "paging": { "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/me/thenovel:rate?sentence=testsentence&access_token=XXXXX&offset=25&limit=25" }}' is all I get... I'm sure I'm doing something obvious wrong because it can't be this difficult to get basic Facebook interaction on a site...

Comment: That looks like the response to a GET request, not a POST request

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in using FB connect first.